# Is output of char* strings through std::wostream defined?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iostream

I just noticed that output of a `char*` through `std::wcout`works totally fine on MSVC (tested with VS2005 and VS 2010).

```
std::wcout << L"Works as expected";
std::wcout << "This ALSO DOES print the string";
```

Indeed, debugging into the output we get to the `<ostream>` header:

```
template<class _Elem, class _Traits> 
inline basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& 
operator<<(basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Ostr, const char *_Val) { ...
```

However, it would appear that this version is not documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba4ae8wb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) nor indeed on [cppref (ostream members)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).

Is this standard? Is this an undocumented MS extension? Does any good come of it?

---

Do note that the opposite will indeed invokde the `void*`output:

```
std::cout << L"Will just print address of string";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least according to [cppref (non-member `operator<<`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) it is defined (see the sixth one down from the top)

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os, 
                                     const char* s );
```

Also, looking at the comments:

> Before insertion, first, all characters are widened using [`os.widen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/widen),
>   then ...

this seems well defined by the C++ standard.

Comment: @MartinBa they should be defined together, it's quite odd that they are on different pages